# How to write a simple login widget in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, authentication, widget

I am  new to zend framework and wigets. can anybody post the code on "how to write a simple login widget.

Comment: voting to close: not a real question. sendmetehcodezplz.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a question but it may be worth you looking at creating a helper method to store the login form.

This question should be of use to you: this may be useful: [Site wide Zend_Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520864/site-wide-zendform)