# Site wide Zend_Form

Tags: php, zend-framework, forms, zend-form

How can I add a form to my layout.phtml?

I would like to be able to have a search form and a login form that persists through every form on my site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a blog post explaining this: http://blog.zero7ict.com/2009/11/how-to-create-reusable-form-zend-framework-zend_form-validation-filters/

In your Application folder create a Forms folder

This is an example form:

```
<?php
class Form_CreateEmail extends Zend_Form
{
public function __construct($options = null)
{
    parent::__construct($options);

    $this->setName('createemail');
    $title = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('title');
    $title->setLabel('Subject')
    ->setRequired(true)
    ->addFilter('StripTags')
    ->addFilter('StringTrim')
    ->addValidator('NotEmpty');
    $info = new Zend_Form_Element_Textarea('info');
    $info->setLabel('Email Content')
    ->setAttribs(array('rows' => 12, 'cols' => 79)); 
    $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
    $submit->setAttrib('id', 'submitbutton');
    $this->addElements(array($title, $info, $submit));
}

}
?>
```

You can then call it from your controller like this:

```
$form = new Form_CreateEmail();
        $form->submit->setLabel('Add');
        $this->view->form = $form;
```

And display it from you view using

```
echo $this->form;
```

Hope this helps.

Edit: if you want this to be included on everypage you could create a new helper file

in your views folder create a helpers folder and create a loginHelper.php file

```
class Zend_View_Helper_LoginHelper
{
    function loginHelper()
    {

$form = new Form_CreateEmail();
        $form->submit->setLabel('Add');
        return = $form;

    }
}
```

This could be output from your layout using:

```
<?php echo $this->LoginHelper(); ?>
```

Comment: Please stick to coding standarts ! your class should be Form_CreateEmail ! (as in Zend_View_Helper_LoginHelper)

Comment: The method `init()` exists so that you don't have to overload `__construct($options)`.

Answer (score 2):

In your Layout just do:

```
$form = new Loginform();
echo $form->render();
```

You just have to make sure that you specify a Controller / Action for the form to POST to, so that is does not POST to whatever Controller you currently are on, wich is the default behaviour.